# SQL left join filters the unmatching records (missing null)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two tables.

1. Calendar : This table contains the date for a year.
2. VisitorTable : This table has date and Count of persons visited.

In the visitor table for few days there are no records.

The date range which has issue is 22-Aug-2014 till 30-Sep-2014.

The date are stored in below format

'2014-08-21 00:00:00.000' and '2014-10-17 00:00:00.000'

On left join of Calendar table with VisitorTable  I am not getting null values for the given date range. The result is present as below

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT VisitingDate ActivityDate
,COUNT(Visit) AS Visits  
FROM CALENDAR A
  LEFT JOIN VisitorTable b
ON B.VisitingDate= A.[DATE]
  WHERE b.StoreName = 'ABC'
```

**Output**

*ActivityDate            Visits*

2014-10-16 00:00:00.000 63

2014-09-30 00:00:00.000 69 

2014-08-22 00:00:00.000 51

**Calendar Table**

```
SELECT *
FROM CALENDAR A
WHERE A.[DATE] BETWEEN '2014-08-22 00:00:00.000'
        AND '2014-09-30 00:00:00.000'
```

**Output**

*DATE*

2014-08-22 00:00:00.000

2014-08-23 00:00:00.000

2014-08-24 00:00:00.000

2014-08-25 00:00:00.000

2014-08-26 00:00:00.000

2014-08-27 00:00:00.000
.

.

.

2014-09-28 00:00:00.000

2014-09-29 00:00:00.000

2014-09-30 00:00:00.000

I am plotting a grpah, thus I need dates with zero vistis.

Pointers will help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE` clause is forcing an implicit `INNER JOIN`.  You need to handle `NULL` values in the `WHERE` clause or specify your conditions as a part of the `LEFT JOIN`.

Try:

```
SELECT VisitingDate ActivityDate
    ,COUNT(Visit) AS Visits  
FROM CALENDAR A
LEFT JOIN VisitorTable b
    ON B.VisitingDate= A.[DATE]
    AND b.StoreName = 'ABC'
GROUP BY VisitingDate
```

Or:

```
SELECT VisitingDate ActivityDate
    ,COUNT(Visit) AS Visits  
FROM CALENDAR A
LEFT JOIN VisitorTable b
    ON B.VisitingDate= A.[DATE]
WHERE b.StoreName = 'ABC'
    OR b.StoreName IS NULL
GROUP BY VisitingDate
```

Comment: your where clause filter helped me. The query was correct but the column which I have chosen was wrong. SELECT C.[DATE] VisitingDate ActivityDate
    ,COUNT(Visit) AS Visits  
FROM CALENDAR A
LEFT JOIN VisitorTable b
    ON B.VisitingDate= A.[DATE]
    AND b.StoreName = 'ABC'

Answer (score 0):

With left join you'll, everything in left table plus anything that matches in the right table.

Your requirement looks like, you need full join or try swapping the joins.

Comment: Since i have selected both column from same table B, I was not able to validate the data and ignoring the nulls. Included the date from table A and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

***Final Query***

```
WITH Gross_Visitor
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.VisitorTable a
    WHERE a.StoreName = 'ABC'
        AND A.ActivityDate BETWEEN '2014-08-22 00:00:00.000'
            AND '2014-10-20 00:00:00.000'
    )
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT C.DATE ActivityDate
        ,COUNT(Visit) AS Visits  
    FROM CALENDAR C
    LEFT JOIN Gross_Visitor O
        ON O.ActivityDate = C.[DATE]
    ) X
    WHERE X.ActivityDate BETWEEN '2014-08-22 00:00:00.000'
            AND '2014-10-20 00:00:00.000'
ORDER BY X.ActivityDate desc;
```